# render .htm page into .aspx page

Tags: asp.net

in my .aspx page i want to render a .htm page which has some data
in  .aspx page i have:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("/Views/Templates/HTML_Temp.htm"); %>
```

but this gives runtime error:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

There is no build provider registered for the extension '.htm'. You can register one in the  section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.

how to resolve this problem...please help

Comment: `Html.RenderPartial()` is part of Asp.net MVC anyway. You're talking about regular web forms aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

### Use #include

The simplest way to put some HTML content in your containing page is by using a server include with `#include`:

```
<!-- #include file="../Templates/HTML_Temp.htm" -->
// for relative paths
```

or

```
<!-- #include virtual="/Views/Templates/HTML_Temp.htm" -->
// for virtual paths
```

### A better way for Asp.net up to 2.0

A better way would of course be to rename your HTML files to ASCX and create a common CS file that doesn't have any particular functionality. Use this same CS file (class relation) with all you newly created ASCX files.

### A better way for Asp.net 2.0 and above

Create a master page (or multitude of them; if you're in 3.0 or higher they can be nested as well) that includes common content and develop other pages on top of your master(s).

Comment: #include no longer works in .NET, does it? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306575

Comment: AFAIK they do work. I can find multiple articles on the net that say it does. Haven't tested it myself. Hence my Second part in the answer.

Comment: Actually, you CAN have nested master pages in ASP 2.0.

See: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/09/vs-2008-nested-master-page-support.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

`<%= File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/Views/Templates/HTML_Temp.htm")) %>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Templates/HTML_Temp.htm")) %>
```